# Laravel selfregistering ServiceProvider

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, package, service-provider

In Laravel 4.2 is it possible to create a package which automatically registers the ServiceProvider without the user adding the path manually to the app.php file?

This way one could just run `composer update` after adding a package to the `composer.json` file and would be ready to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that there is no way to register your main service provider than putting it in the `app.php` file. In fact you can, but it will always require something from the developer. You can't get away with it with a simple `composer update`.

You can register sub service providers with `App::register('MyApp\Providers\MyServiceProvider');` inside your package.

Comment: Darn, is that technically impossible? Or is it just not build into the system?

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no way for a package to register itself.